# Как сделать gif фон активности android приложения

Tags: android

Основная идея в заголовке, возможно ли это и если да, то как?

Comment: Да. 1. Записать её на видео. 2. Сконвертировать видео в gif.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а в чем логика? Как ее устанавливать, есть ли статьи?

Comment: Про логику нигде не говорится.

Comment: У Android Studio нет ативностей. Это desktop приложение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй glide

```
Glide
.with(context)
.load(R.raw.youGif)
.into(imageView);
```

https://github.com/bumptech/glide